# How to Console.Read() n number of lines from Asterisk AGI

Tags: c#, asterisk, agi

I am communicating with Asterisk via AGI, so im using:

```
Console.WriteLine(command);
```

and then:

```
string res = Console.ReadLine();
```

to read the response.

This all works fine almost all of the time.

When the response has multiple lines, only first line is read.
eg:

```
<Message/ast_msg_queue>AGI Tx >> 200 result=1 (Line 1
Line 2)
```

How do I read the response even if it's n lines long?

Tests so far:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int x;
while (true) {
    x = Console.Read();
    if (x == -1) break; // This never occurs

    sb.Append(Convert.ToChar(x));
}
```

The above code creates an infinite loop, and so does this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string line;
while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null) {
    sb.AppendLine(line);
}
```

Comment: any reason why you not use ready-made library?

Comment: Because this is an already established project that does many other things.

Answer (score -1):

End of AGI command - empty line.

So you shoudl read all upto empty line, discard that line. EVERYTIME.

Or just read source of already compleated libs. There are tens of them.

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-agi/